# mysql query how to find this record

Tags: php, mysql

my table structure

```
id   event_id   tag_id
1     18         2
2     18         3
3     18         10
4     18         14
5     18         175
```

`SELECT * from event_table where tag_id = 176 and tag_id IN(2,3,10)`

I need those record which have 175 record and any record which come in array()

Comment: Use `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: Question not clear ... "I need those record which have 175 record and any record which come in array()" ?

Comment: If i am using or the it show wrong result

Comment: what do you mean by any...tag_id 176 must and only one from array or else.

Comment: Clear your question ..what exactly you want...

Comment: do you differentiate between numbers 175 and 176, or for the sake of this question you assume they are equal? :-)

Comment: if i write query select * from table where tag_id = 175 and tag_id in (1,3,4)... It will be show the result which have tag_id = 175,3 tag id result

Comment: Still not clear deepak....you can mention what output you want so someone can create a new query and help you.

Comment: this is relation ship table.... event id is foreign key here.. I have filter option. I need those event which have tagid = (1,2,4)(tag_id) any one on this and 175(tag) will compulsory

Comment: Please try below answer I posted ..hope that will help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you want back, but assuming you want all the details from the events table for a tag of 2, 3 or 10 for events which also have a tag of 175 then I would possibly do a join, with one occurrence of the table being for tag_id 175 and then check in the WHERE clause for one of the the other tags on the other occurrence of the table.

```
SELECT a.id, a.event_id, a.tag_id
FROM event_table a
INNER JOIN event_table b
ON a.event_id = b.event_id
AND b.tag_id = 175
WHERE a.tag_id IN (2,3,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the sub query...and get the desired result what you want

```
SELECT e.*
   FROM
       (SELECT * 
          FROM event_table
          WHERE tag_id = 175
       ) AS e
       JOIN
       (SELECT * 
           FROM event_table
           WHERE tag_id IN(2,3,4)
       ) AS e1 
      ON e1.event_id = e.event_id;
```

Hope this will help...

Answer (score 0):

Thinking that you want this:

```
SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE (tag_id = 175 OR tag_id IN(2,3,10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `or` to find rows with tag_id = 175 OR tag id is one of your array entries. Use implode to construct comma separated list of ids:

```
$id = 175;
$tagIds = array(2,3,10);
$sql = "$sql = SELECT * from event_table where tag_id = " . (int) $id . " or tag_id IN(" . implode(',', $tagIds) . ")";
```

Be aware that you have to verify that only integer numbers are stored in `$id`and `$tagIds`as using user input may introduce sql injection possibilities.

Using `mysqli*()`functions and prepared statements is strongly recommended.

Comment: i have 2 event
1st event contain tag_id = 1,2,3,4, 175
2nd event contain tag_id = 1,2,3,5,7,176
if i use your query then second record also come ... but second record do not have 175 tag id.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to think about:

```
SELECT event_id 
     , MAX(tag_id = 175)
     , MAX(tag_id IN(2,3,10))
  FROM event_table
 GROUP 
    BY event_id;
```

So, then you can have something like...

```
SELECT event_id 
  FROM event_table
 GROUP 
    BY event_id
HAVING MAX(tag_id = 175)
   AND MAX(tag_id IN(2,3,10));
```

...or subtle variations of that. For instance, if you wanted events with 175 AND at least 2 out of the 3 tags (2,3,10), that might be:

```
SELECT event_id 
  FROM event_table
 GROUP 
    BY event_id
HAVING SUM(tag_id = 175) >= 1
   AND SUM(tag_id IN(2,3,10)) >= 2;
```